# postgres liquibase limit diff to one schema

Tags: postgresql, diff, liquibase

Goal:

I created a special login  (named `liquibase`) which has only acces to one schema `CustomerXX` (the schema which I would like to compare and only this!!)

Problem:

Even with this login limited the liquibase diff operations try to read other schema (as exemple in my error obsolete_objects)

Remark:

I am studing the CustomerXX. I have another schema in the database named `obsolete_objects` but i am only focus on customerxx

```
login liquibase  used ==>
GRANT all ON  schema customerxx to liquibase;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA customerxx to liquibase;
no other right
```

My command liquibase:

```
liquibase.bat 
    --classpath="E:\Program Files\Talend-Studio\plugins\org.talend.libraries.jdbc.postgresql_5.5.1.r118616\lib\postgresql-9.2-1003.jdbc3.jar" 
    --driver=org.postgresql.Driver --url=jdbc:postgresql://xxxxxxxxx  
    --username=USERNAME 
    --password=PASSWORD 
    --defaultSchemaName=customerxx  
    Diff 
    --referenceUrl=jdbc:postgresql://yyyyyyyyyy 
    --referenceUsername=liquibase 
    --referencePassword=liquibase 
    --referenceDefaultSchemaName=customerxx
```

My error

```
Diff Results:

Unexpected error running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: permission denied for schema obsolete_objects Positioná: 27
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am confused on what you intend. I might suggest you return the liquibase.bat back to its original default values, and put your specific flags into a liquibase.properties file. If my memory serves, I never was successfull at running all the flags I needed from a command prompt. Be sure the liquibase.properties file is in the same directory as the liquibase.jar executable. Also, in your above .bat, be sure the username and password are good for both the defaultSchemaName and the referenceDefaultSchemaName.  (I left mine as postgres).